# Dynamically creating and loading a dynamic page into a browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I hope I can explain what I would like to do a bit better than how I did with the question's title :)

I have a page whose content is dynamically generated. I would like to:

a- grab certain divs out of it,
b- wrap them with the markup of a standard html page (html, head, body, ...)
c- load the result into a separate browser window

I can do a & b but not sure how to do c. Any thoughts on how this can be done would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I think any pages open in a browser should need to have its own URL. So it's not really possible for you to do it unless the page can be generated at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open an "empty" html document in a popup window, and then add the elements to that document. So, rather than creating a document and then displaying it, display an empty shell, and then fill in the content.

Found this tutorial after some quick googling: http://www.openjs.com/tutorials/advanced_tutorial/popup.php
(just don't use global variables like they do)

Comment: Cool! i should have looked at the problem the other way around :) thanks for the response and the tutorial link. cheers!